# Finding closest value. How to tell MySQL that the data is already ordered?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like the following:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+
| datetime   | double     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| some_value | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Date is necessary to be in double and is registered in unix time with fractional seconds (no possibility to install `mysql 5.6` to use fractional `DATETIME`). In addition, the values of the field `datetime` are not only primary, they are also always increasing. I would like to find the closest row to certain value. Usually you can use something like:

```
select * from table order by abs(datetime - $myvalue) limit 1
```

However, I'm afraid that this implementation will be slow for hundred thousands of values, because it is going to search in all the database. And since I have an ordered list, I know I can do some `binary search` to speed up the process, but I have no idea how to tell `MySQL` to perform such kind of search.

In order to test the performance I do the following lines:

```
SET profiling = 1;
SELECT * FROM table order by abs(datetime - $myvalue) limit 1;
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
```

With the following results:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000122 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000051 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000191 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000038 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000094 |
| System lock                    | 0.000047 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000085 |
| init                           | 0.000103 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000031 |
| statistics                     | 0.000057 |
| preparing                      | 0.000049 |
| executing                      | 0.000023 |
| Sorting result                 | 2.806665 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000359 |
| end                            | 0.000049 |
| query end                      | 0.000033 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000050 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000089 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000067 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000032 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Which in my understanding, the sorting the result takes 2.8 seconds, however my data is already sorted. As additional information, I have around 240,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

It won't scan the entire database. A primary key is indexed by a B-tree. Forcing it into a binary search would be *slower,* if you could do it, which you can't.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the performance? since I know that the table is ordered. Because it will cause a lot of unnecessary computation otherwise.

Comment: Speed up the performance from what? Where your evidence that there is a performance problem? Have you run an EXPLAIN on that query? Done anything except guess?

Comment: This is the result of the explain command `1 | SIMPLE      | table_name | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 236683 (rows) | Using filesort`. As you said, it is a guess that MySQL is performing `abs(datetime - $myvalue)` for every field since I'm not able to see other workaround to skip the operation without telling it otherwise. I'll verify more in detail. In any case it got me wondering because the query takes 2.8 seconds (it is in a RPI 3 though).

Comment: I'm puzzled as to what you think it can perform this binary chop *on*. If there was a WHERE clause, it can match those values or ranges out of an index, but if there isn't, there is nothing to search, or binary-chop on.

Comment: In fact, I'm acquiring data in at a frequency of let's say around (but not exactly) 4Hz. Then I'm storing the information of that data, the time in fractional seconds and the value I received. Once the data is stored, at some point I need to get the value received at a requested time which is not exactly the same as the stored time, that's why I need the closest time. And since the data is ordered, that is the reason I believed the data could be chopped in half every time it searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a field:

```
select abs(datetime - $myvalue) as date_diff, table.*
from table
order by date_diff
limit 1
```

Comment: The query I have already gives me the result I want. That's not the problem. The problem is that I know that my data is ordered, therefore a binary search will be way faster when I have a binary search like implementation, splitting the table as needed and performing close to `O(log n)`

Comment: Way faster than what?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are supported in RDBMSs. Define an index on date time or field of your interest and db will not do the complete table scan

Comment: I already have a primary index in the `datetime` field as indicated in the question. However, I don't know any increment key (only auto_increment which is not the case) to tell mysql to find the value more efficiently.